# What is CR8supplement in my Font Book? Should I delete it?

Tags: font, font-book, ventura

I’m currently using my MacBook Pro with macOS Ventura installed, and a font file is bugging me. An installed font called *CR8supplement*. The font is sitting in my Font Book and, to be honest, I don’t even know what this is.

Like the repertoire shows nothing but two poorly designed Apple logos (labeled *nonmarkingreturn* and *dmacron*) next to a checkmark (hilariously labeled as a *plus sign*).
[image: a screenshot of a font book showing the CR8supplement font]
I don’t know what to do with this weird font. What is this font? Should I delete it or do something with it?

Comment: Any chance you have this installed?   https://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html

Comment: @TomGewecke I once had typelight installed before, although i deleted it because i’m not using it for daily use anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this font, and it's not part of Ventura (AFAICT).

It looks like it's installed in the User fonts folder (being under "My Fonts" in Font Book), rather than the `/Library` or `/System` fonts folders.

> Should I delete it or do something with it?

Your choices are: leave it as it is; disable it in Font Book; or delete/remove it.

If you delete it, at worst, something will display with missing glyph symbols. Because you have a backup, you can always restore it later.